# Separate information sent via Serial

Tags: java, c++, python, serial-port, arduino

I recently bought an Arduino with an LCD screen. I want to push information from my computer to the Arduino. I came across a great article, *[How to make a physical Gmail notifier](http://j4mie.org/blog/how-to-make-a-physical-gmail-notifier/)*. From what I understand, I have to send the information using Serial and read it in the C/C++ code on the Arduino. That is fine, but I want to send different information to the device.

Say I want to have one part of the LCD-screen showing the temperature outside and another part of the screen display when the next bus is coming. Is there any way to "mark" the information I send with Serial, or does everything end up in the same "channel"?

If that is the case, is there a logical, simple way to separate this information so it does not mistake bus-information for temperature and vice versa?

Comment: You have to invent a [communications protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol) to handle the different events. It's actually not as hard as it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a protocol for sending information across the serial line, so that the data can be collected the other end in a way that makes sense. A simple protocol may be:

```
 T:16.0 09.34      // Temperature, 16.0°C measured at 09.34
 B:11b 11.46       // Bus, route 11b, arrives at 11.46 at your bus-stop. 
 M:mats@example.com 11kb 10.23    // Mail from mats@example.com, it's 11KB and arrived at 10.23
```

Each line contains one type of information.

Assuming the line of communication is reliable (and as long as your wire isn't several dozen feet, it should be), you don't need more than that. If the communicatio is unreliable, you need some sort of "start" and "end" markers (or a start and a length), a checksum and some way of dealing with "it went wrong". You will also need to read with a timeout, so that when you don't get enough data, the system starts over again with the next bit of information.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! By the looks of it, Arduino actually has this exact solution for separating Serial-communication built in by default. Superb, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to "mark" the information I send with Serial

Definitely. YOU decide how the information is sent if you have control over the information passing over the serial port on your computer.

> or does everything end up in the same "channel"?

Well, the serial port is a kind of a channel I guess, since all information you wish to send to the Arduino goes over the port.

> is there a logical, simple way to separate this information so it does not mistake bus-information for temperature and vice versa.

Yes. Say you want to send temperature data. Create a byte array for example in this manner: {T23.4} = Temperature data

The bracket '{' signals to the receiving code in the arduino that information is coming down the line with some data. The letter T indicates temperature. Everything after the letter 'T' up to the '}' is data. (23.4)

Bus information could be {Bxxx} where xxx is the data.